# properties of outer measure

Tags: measure-theory

Let X be a set and an outer measure on X is a function $\theta:\mathcal{P} X \to [0,\infty]$ such that

(i) $\theta \phi= 0$

(ii) if $A \subseteq B \subseteq X$ then $\theta A \leq \theta B$.

(iii)  for every sequence $<A_n>_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of subsets of X, $\theta(\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n) \leq \sum^\infty_{n=1} \theta A_n$

If we combine (i) and (iii) and if $\theta$ is an outer measure on X , and A and B are two subsets of X, how do we get $\theta(A \cup B) \leq \theta A + \theta B$?

Answer (score 2):

Use this sequence:  $A_1 = A$, $A_2 = B$, and $A_n = \varnothing$ for all other $n$.